# Android Root Certificates, by Android Version

Tags: android, ios, x509

For each version of iOS Apple publishes a list of the embedded root certificates:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205205

I am unable to find something similar for Android, I am wondering if these could differ by device vendor or if they all share a common set as part of Android proper?

My goal is to have a list of public CAs which are commin in both Android and iOS (some minimum version of each)

Comment: "I am wondering if these could differ by device vendor" -- quite possibly, particularly on older device versions. Google is now capable of updating the certificate list independently of firmware updates (starting with 4.4?), and I do not know whether vendors have any way of supporting other root certificates beyond Google's list on those versions.

Comment: Thank you, it appears that Android and Linux both use the Mozilla bundle but the device vendor can add/remove. https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy#TOC-Root-Certificate-Programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is curious, I believe I found the answer:

> **Linux:** There is no central root certificate program as part of Linux. When running on Linux, Google Chrome uses the Mozilla Network
>   Security Services (NSS) library to perform certificate verification.
>   When packaged or built from source, NSS includes certificates vetted
>   according to the Mozilla Root Certificate Program. For most Linux
>   users, it is sufficient that once included in the Mozilla Root
>   Program, users of Google Chrome should see your root CA as trusted.
>   However, please be aware that Linux distributions which package NSS
>   may further alter this list with additions or removals based on local,
>   distribution-specific root certificate programs, if any.
>
> **Android**: Please file a bug at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry .
>
> Note that, similar to Linux, the certificates included within the
>   Android sources may be further altered by device manufacturers or
>   carriers, pursuant to their local programs.

https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy#TOC-Root-Certificate-Programs

Mozilla bundle:

https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:IncludedCAs